# Conditional concatenation in Data Weave

Tags: concatenation, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

Is there a way to do conditional concatenation of a string. For instance, if the string has a value then add it, but if the string is null then don't. I am creating a long string that will become the body of an email message. The "payload.eachRecipient.company" field may have a value or may be null. I want to include the line in the email only if it has a value, but not display the "Company Name:" line if it doesn't.

```
payload.eachRecipient.city ++ ", " ++ payload.eachRecipient.state ++ " " ++ payload.eachRecipient.zipCode ++ "\n\n" ++
("Company Name: " ++ payload.eachRecipient.company (if payload.eachRecipient.company?)) ++ "\n" ++ "ID: " ++ payload.eachRecipient.sson ++ "\n" ++ "System Order Number: " ++ payload.eachRecipient.orderNum ++ "\n\n" ++
"Shipping Method: " ++ payload.eachRecipient.ShipVia ++ "\n\n" ++ "Order Summary:\n" ++ (vars.listOfMaterials.combinedString joinBy("\n")) ++
```

Comment: 'when' doesn't work either: ("" when payload.eachRecipient.company==null otherwise "Company Name: " ++ payload.eachRecipient.company)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a function that takes the string that will be checked for a null value, anything you want to add to the front and anything you want to add to the back:

```
fun checkNull(aString, aFront, aBack) = 
    if (aString == null)
        ""
    else
        aFront ++ aString ++ aBack
```

The result of the function is concatenated into the longer string:

```
(checkNull(payload.eachRecipient.company, "Company Name: ", "\n"))
checkNull(payload.eachRecipient.line2, "", "\n\t")
```

Answer (score 0):

Conditional concatenation works perfectly fine

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
'one ' 
++ ' two ' 
++ (if (true) ' three' else ' THREE')
++ (if (false) ' four' else ' FOUR')
```

[image]

Comment: Will a null value be 'true' or 'false'? And in my case I am prepending a field title and appending a new line character.

Comment: null is not true or false. To have boolean - do vars.abc == null. New line is perfectly good character as any other.